# InfluxDB storage size on disk

Tags: influxdb

All I want is simply to know how much space my InfluxDB database takes on my HDD. The stats() command gives me dozens of numbers but I don't know which one shows what I want.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Stats output does not contain that information. The size of the directory structure on disk will give that info.

```
du -sh /var/lib/influxdb/data/<db name>
```

Where `/var/lib/influxdb/data` is the data directory defined in `influxdb.conf`.

Comment: Is there any way to check it using the influx CLI?

Comment: For InfluxDB 2.0, the path is `du -sh /var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/`

Comment: There are other built-in options for InfluxDB v1.x and v2.x. See my findings in the other thread below.

Comment: For InfluxDB v2.7.5 the path is `du -sh /var/lib/influxdb2/engine/data/`

Answer (score 3):

In InfluxDB [v1.x](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/influx_inspect/#report-disk), you can use following command to find out the disk usage of database, measurement and even shards:

```
influx_inspect report-disk -detailed /var/lib/influxdb/data/
```

[image]

In InfluxDB v2.x, you could take advantage of the internal stats as following:

```
from(bucket: "yourBucket")
    |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "storage_shard_disk_size")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "gauge")
    |> last()
```

It will show you the size of each database.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also check `.influxdb` in your user's home directory.

If you already run `influxd`, you can check which file descriptors it keeps open:

```
$ pgrep -a influxd
<influxd PID> <full command path>
$ ls -l /proc/<influxd PID>/fd
```

For example, I have an `influxd` from a prebuilt package `influxdb-1.8.6_linux_amd64.tar.gz`. It is simply unpacked in `/home/me/bin/` and runs as a user command. There is neither `/var/lib/influxdb/` nor `/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf`. There is `~/bin/influxdb-1.8.6-1/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf`, but it is not actually used. However, the list of file descriptors in `/proc/<PID>/fd` shows that it keeps several files opened under:

```
/home/me/.influxdb/data
/home/me/.influxdb/data/<my_db_name>/_series
/home/me/.influxdb/wal/<my_db_name>/
```

But do not take this for granted, I am not an `influxdb` expert. Notice that 1.8 is an old version, there might be some tricks in other versions.

Answer (score 0):

For InfluxDB 2.0 on MacOS - (for me at least) - the location is ~/.influxdbv2/engine.

Running "du -sh *" will show you the disk usage.