# In Influxdb 2.0, how to find a bucket's size in bytes on disk?

Tags: size, influxdb, bucket, influxdb-2

I can certainly find out the size on disk of ALL buckets (`du -sh .` from the data dir), but it's unclear how I do this for a single bucket because the data doesn't seem organized in the file system by bucket.

It would be nice if this info was visible in their web UI admin interface.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InfluxDB storage size on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44454836/influxdb-storage-size-on-disk)